# Relevance of the featured question on app feed

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ios-app-feed

Since the 'featured question' has been added to the app, there is now the overwhelming chance that 3/4 of the opening app screen is of no interest to me. (I participate in 5 out of X stack sites, the odds aren't too good!)

[image: App feed]

I personally think that's a pretty huge amount of screen space to dedicate to a single question - but if it's here to stay, can the question at least be chosen from sites I participate in? The app feed already has a significant amount of space dedicated to hot network questions from sites I'm not interested in, it would be great if it could be more relevant to me as a user.